# load codebehind Gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, gridview

I am generating this tags (IT,Marketing....) dynamically(codebehind) from the sql using linq to sql.

And when you click on any of the the tabs it will show the **gridview** as per table created in database.

But the gridview binding is done during page_load event, so everything is generated during page_load, now when you click any of the blue tabs , it will show you pre-generated gridviews.

Now i want to generate or load gridviews when i clck on [+] sign of any of the tabs and not during the page load

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
     <div id="CONTAINER" onclick="">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

             <div class="clickable mfiles" onclick="showHide('subm');changesign('signm');">
                    <span id="signm" class="plusMinus">[+]</span><span> M-Files<br />
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div id="subm">


                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

                </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>





         </div>
    <br />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</form>

<script>


    function showHide(id) {
        __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', id);
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        //if (el && el.style.display == 'block') {
        //    el.style.display = 'none';
        //}

        //else {
        //    el.style.display = 'block';
        //}


    }

    function changesign(id1) {
        var xy = document.getElementById(id1);
        if (xy.innerHTML == "[-]") {
            xy.innerHTML = "[+]";
        }

        else {
            xy.innerHTML = "[-]";
        }
    }

</script>
```

banckend code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
CONTACT_INFODataContext context = new CONTACT_INFODataContext("Data Source=BPM-IT116;Initial Catalog=FORM_GET;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=spreader;Password=Red_Sky");
                var depts = context.spi_GetNoOfDept();
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();

                int i = 1;
                foreach (spi_GetNoOfDeptResult dept in depts)
                {
                    Literal div = new Literal();
                    Contact deptinfo = new Contact();
                    deptinfo.NAME_LAST = dept.DEPT_NAME;
                    deptinfo.DEPT_ID = dept.DEPT_ID.ToString();



                    div.Text = "<div class=\"even clickable\" onclick=\"showHide('sub" + dept.DEPT_ID + "');changesign('sign" + dept.DEPT_ID + "');\">";
                    div.Text += "<span id=\"sign" + dept.DEPT_ID + "\">[+]</span><span>" + dept.DEPT_NAME + "</span>";
                    div.Text += "</div>";


                    div.Text += "<div id=\"sub" + dept.DEPT_ID + "\" style=\"margin-left:15px ;\">";



                    //GridView gd = CreateDynamicTable(dept.DEPT_ID);

                    i++;

                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(div);

                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
        }

   private GridView CreateDynamicTable(int x)
        {
            GridView gd = new GridView();

            gd.ID = "grd" + x;
            gd.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "altrowstyle1";
            gd.RowStyle.CssClass = "rowstyle1";
            gd.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "grdhdr";
            gd.GridLines = GridLines.None;
            List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();


            CONTACT_INFODataContext context = new CONTACT_INFODataContext("Data Source=BPM-IT116;Initial Catalog=FORM_GET;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=spreader;Password=Red_Sky");
            var persons = context.spi_GetContacts();
            var items = context.spi_GetDept(x);
            var depts = context.spi_GetNoOfDept();

            foreach (spi_GetDeptResult item in items)
            {

                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.NAME_LAST = item.NAME_LAST;
                contact.NAME_FIRST = item.NAME_FIRST;
                contact.PHONE_CELL = item.PHONE_CELL;
                contact.ADDRESS = item.ADDRESS;
                contact.APT = item.APT;
                contact.DEPT_ID = item.DEPT_ID.ToString();
                contact.DEPT_NAME = item.DEPT_NAME;

                contacts.Add(contact);
                //ddl_db.Items.Add(new ListItem(person.NAME_FIRST));
            }
            gd.CssClass = "gdmain";


            gd.DataSource = contacts;
            gd.DataBind();

            return gd;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Multiview control for your tab container then you should be able to bind your code to load the Gridview to the ActiveViewChanged event and change your ActiveViewIndex property for that Multiview when your users navigate between your tabs.